# C# MySQL multiline result to comboBoxes

Tags: c#, mysql, foreach

I have 5 comboBoxes, 5 textboxes and 5 numericUpDowns that I need to fill with the data of a multiline query.

The result of the query is:

```
clave   descr                             canti
ABR002  ABRAZADERA DE RIEL UNICANAL 1"      1
ABR003  ABRAZADERA DE RIEL UNICANAL 1/2"    2
ABR004  ABRAZADERA DE RIEL UNICANAL 3/4"    3
ABR005  ABRAZADERA PARA TUBING 18 CM        4
ABR006  ABRAZADERA DE RIEL UNICANAL 2 1/2"  5
```

The code I used for retrieving data from query lines was:

```
try
{
    MySqlCommand cmdc = new MySqlCommand("select clave, descr, canti from notaspd where folio = '" + comboBox6.Text + "';", conn);
    MySqlDataAdapter dataadapc = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdc);
    System.Data.DataTable datatabc = new System.Data.DataTable();
    dataadapc.Fill(datatabc);

    foreach (DataRow row in datatabc.Rows)
    {
        rows = string.Format("{0}", row.ItemArray[0]);
        comboBox1.Text = rows;
        rows = string.Format("{0}", row.ItemArray[1]);
        textBox3.Text = rows;
        rows = string.Format("{0}", row.ItemArray[2]);
        numericUpDown1.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(rows);                        
    }
}
```

But if I do that, all the comboBoxes, textBoxes and nUD are filled with the last line giving me something like:

```
ABR006  ABRAZADERA DE RIEL UNICANAL 2 1/2"  5
ABR006  ABRAZADERA DE RIEL UNICANAL 2 1/2"  5
ABR006  ABRAZADERA DE RIEL UNICANAL 2 1/2"  5
ABR006  ABRAZADERA DE RIEL UNICANAL 2 1/2"  5
ABR006  ABRAZADERA DE RIEL UNICANAL 2 1/2"  5
```

I understand that this is because the foreach cycle goes all the way to the last result and overprints the last one. How can I modify the foreach so it returns only the n-line result?

I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's late here, so forgive me if I'm missing something!

You're storing each individual cell in a separate control, so why not just access each cell in the `DataTable` and set the appropriate control?

```
comboBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(datatabc.Rows[0][0]);
...
comboBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(datatabc.Rows[4][0]);

textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(datatabc.Rows[0][1]);
...
textBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(datatabc.Rows[4][1]);

numericUpDown1.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(datatabc.Rows[0][2]);
...
numericUpDown5.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(datatabc.Rows[4][2]);
```

I just don't see a reason for using a `foreach` loop here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
foreach (DataRow row in datatabc.Rows)
{
   comboBox1.Text = string.Format("{0}", row["clave"]);
   textBox3.Text =  string.Format("{0}", row["descr"]);
   numericUpDown1.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0}", row["canti"]));                        
}
```

[edit]
you may need the ".ToString()" - ex. row["clave"].ToString()